# Button "Details" not triggering the expected behavior in nested loop structure

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am facing an issue with the functionality of the "Details" button in my HTML code, and I am seeking assistance in identifying the problem.

I have a nested loop structure where I display information about countries, companies, and job vacancies.
Each country has a set of companies, and each company has a set of job vacancies.
The "Details" button is intended to reveal additional information about job vacancies when clicked.
When I click the "Details" button, nothing happens, and the job vacancies are not displayed as expected.
Here is my code

```
<div class="country-card" data-country="Угорщина">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/hungary.png') }}" alt="Угорщина Прапор">
        <span>Угорщина</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="country-card" data-country="Словаччина">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/slovakia.png') }}" alt="Словаччина Прапор">
        <span>Словаччина</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="country-card" data-country="Чехія">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/czech-republic.png') }}" alt="Чехія Прапор">
        <span>Чехія</span>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
    @foreach(['Угорщина', 'Словаччина', 'Чехія'] as $country)
    <!-- Блок країни -->
    <div class="country-block" id="{{ $country }}">
        <h2>{{ $country }}</h2>
        <div class="company-cards">
            @foreach($project->where('country', $country) as $rs)
                <!-- Картка компанії в обраній країні -->
                <div class="card company-card" style="" data-country="{{ $country }}" data-company="{{ $rs->company }}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ $rs->company }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ $rs->city }}</p>

                        <!--Details button -->
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary details-btn">DETAILS</button> <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                @foreach($project->where('company', $rs->company) as $vacancy)
                    <!-- Картка вакансії для обраної компанії -->
                    <div class="card vacancy-card" style="margin: 10px;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $vacancy->vacancy }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ $vacancy->job }}</p> 
                            
                            <!-- Кнопка "Створити PDF" для вакансії -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary details-btn" onclick="openPDFEditor('{{ $vacancy->id }}')">Створити PDF</button>

                            <!-- Модальне вікно редактора PDF для вакансії -->
                            <div id="pdfEditorModal_{{ $vacancy->id }}" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); z-index: 9999; ">
                                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                    <h3>Редактор PDF</h3>
                                    <!-- Кнопка закриття модального вікна -->
                                    <button type="button" onclick="closePDFEditor('{{ $vacancy->id }}')">✖</button>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div style="display: flex;" >
                                    <div id="pdfPreview" style="margin-right: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;  "></div>
                                    <div>
                                        <!-- Форма для введення даних перед створенням PDF -->
                                        <label for="name">Країна</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="name" required>
                                        <br>
                                        <label for="email">Назва проекту\заводу</label>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" required>
                                        <br>
                                        <!-- Кнопки для операцій з PDF -->
                                        <button type="button" onclick="generateAndPreviewPDF()">Створити і Переглянути PDF</button>
                                        <br> <br>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="downloadPDF()">Завантажити PDF</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.country-block, .company-cards, .vacancy-card, .details-btn').hide();
    
            $('.country-card').on('click', function(){
                var countryId = $(this).data('country');
    
                $('.country-block').hide();
                $('#'+countryId).show();
    
                $('.company-cards').hide();
                $('#'+countryId+' .company-cards').show();
    
                $('.details-btn').show();
            });
    
            $(document).on('click', '.details-btn', function(){
                $('.vacancy-card').hide();
                $(this).closest('.company-card').find('.vacancy-card').show();
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure how one is supposed to see the details button to click it, when it's nested within `.company-cards`, which is hidden when the document is loaded.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.company-card').find('.vacancy-card').show();` will not work because `.vacancy-card` isn't a child of `.company-card`. Either your HTML structure is off from what you intended, or you'll need some kind of lookup - I'd suggest using the index of the loop to create a data attribute on the button and the vacancy card that will match them up on click